# PowerShell - Outlook Object does not support Read-Host

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am having some trouble with a PowerShell script that I made that I thought was working last week.

It takes a date the user types in and sets a calendar invite for it:

```
[string]$datetime = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a Date and Time (1/23/45 9:05AM)"    

$olAppointmentItem = 1 

$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application 

#Each new calendar appointment must have the CreateItem and Save lines

$a = $o.CreateItem($olAppointmentItem) 

################ Broken #########################
#$a.Start = $datetime - fails
$a.Start = [string]"9/9/2015 15:00" # - works
####################################
$a.Duration = 30 
$a.Subject = $sql_sub
$a.Body = $sql_desc
$a.Location = $sql_loc
$a.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15 
$a.ReminderSet = $True 

$result = $a.Save()
```

Basically by manually putting the string on the `$a.Start` object it works correctly, but when you assign it using the variable `$datetime` it fail with this error message:

```
The object does not support this method. At C:\Users\jmasse\Desktop\PowerShell Projects\Ticket to Calendar Invite\Query SW from PS.ps1:76 char:2
+     $a.Start = $datetime
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I am putting the correct date format in when it gets read from the `Read-Host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a String object instead of a DateTime Object,

Replace this:

```
[string]$datetime = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a Date and Time (1/23/45 9:05AM)"
```

With this:

```
[DateTime]$datetime = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a Date and Time (1/23/45 9:05AM)"
```

Then you can use:

```
$a.Start = $datetime
```

Comment: Ugh...I thought I did that before, but I must have fat-fingered [DateTime] or put it in the wrong spot. Thanks a bunch. Edit: I guess I got confused with the [string] in from of the actual string in my script.